# Fetching records without specific subdocument or with specific subdocument and other conditions

Tags: mongodb

I'm stuck!

Consider having these products in a products collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("53678a557e6e9e19dd4ef1c8"),
    name: "product 1",
    rules: [
        {
            type: "one_purchase_per_user"
        }
    ],
    stock: 0,
    unlimited_stock: true
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("53678a557e6e9e19dd4ef1c7"),
    name: "product 2",
    rules: [],
    stock: 0,
    unlimited_stock: true
}
```

And a user has already bought to following product: `ObjectId("53678a557e6e9e19dd4ef1c8")`

I'm trying to receive all products which have a stock greater than 0 or unlimited_stock AND which either dont have the `one_purchase_per_user` rule or (if they do) havent already been purchased by the specific user with the following query:

```
db.products.find({
    '$and': [
        { '$or': [
            { stock: { '$gt': 0 } },
            { unlimited_stock: true }
        ] },
        { '$or': [ 
            { 'rules.type': 'one_purchase_per_user', _id: { $nin: [ObjectId("53678a557e6e9e19dd4ef1c8")] } },
            { 'rules.type': { '$ne': 'one_purchase_per_user' } }
        ] }
    ]
})
```

I get the following error:

```
error: { "$err" : "assertion src/mongo/db/query/plan_enumerator.cpp:1040" }
```

If i remove the part about $nin or change the field name on either of the last $or conditions the query succeeds but then the condition makes no sense since its not accomplishing what i want it to do.

I'm running mongodb 2.6.0

**Edit: I figured out what caused the error, but i dont know why: I had an index on rules.type, if i removed that index the query works**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding your Products and executing your query I get the following result (using MongoDB shell 2.4.9):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53678a557e6e9e19dd4ef1c7"), "name" : "product 2",
  "rules" : [ ], "stock" : 0, "unlimited_stock" : true }
```

So it is working for me.
Try to quote `$nin` and `_id` like you did it with your other tags: `'$nin'` and `'_id'`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out what it was, it was because i had an index on rules.type

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar issue after an upgrade to mongodb 2.6.1

There's a bug fix probably coming in 2.6.2 - here's the bug report:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13714

From a comment in the JIRA issue

> It's not exactly $or related but instead a problem with how we generate plans for $not queries that can use an index.